# error while giving maven clean. working on git plgin

Tags: java, eclipse, git, maven, jenkins

I took the source of [git plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/git-plugin) for my jenkins into eclipse(kepler). then I gave a maven clean. But after the clean I got following error:

```
The method `configRoundtrip`(FreeStyleProject) is ambiguous for the type GitSCMTest
```

The java file, `GitSCMTest.java` resides under `hudson.plugins.git` package under `src/test/java`.

And when i try to give maven clean the console says,

```
Failed to load class SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Jenkins GIT plugin 2.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1:clean (default-clean) @ git ---
[INFO] Deleting D:\CI\git-plugin-master\target
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.304s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Oct 22 15:59:47 IST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 6M/150M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1:clean (default-clean) on project git: Failed to clean project: Failed to delete D:\CI\git-plugin-master\target\surefire\surefirebooter9216743649885094480.jar -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

By deleting target folder from the source folder, the above error got solved.
But now, when i say maven install, I get these errors,

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Jenkins GIT plugin 2.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-hpi-plugin:1.96:validate (default-validate) @ git ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.0-beta-1:display-info (default) @ git ---
[INFO] Maven Version: 3.0.4
[INFO] JDK Version: 1.7.0_07 normalized as: 1.7.0-7
[INFO] OS Info: Arch: amd64 Family: windows Name: windows 7 Version: 6.1
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-localizer-plugin:1.14:generate (default) @ git ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ git ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 106 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ git ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- access-modifier-checker:1.4:enforce (default-enforce) @ git ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- bridge-method-injector:1.4:process (default) @ git ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-hpi-plugin:1.96:insert-test (default-insert-test) @ git ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- gmaven-plugin:1.3:generateTestStubs (test-in-groovy) @ git ---
[INFO] No sources found for Java stub generation
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:testResources (default-testResources) @ git ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 4 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ git ---
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to D:\CI\git-plugin-master\target\test-classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-hpi-plugin:1.96:test-hpl (default-test-hpl) @ git ---
[INFO] Generating D:\CI\git-plugin-master\target\test-classes\the.hpl
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-hpi-plugin:1.96:resolve-test-dependencies (default-resolve-test-dependencies) @ git ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- gmaven-plugin:1.3:testCompile (test-in-groovy) @ git ---
[INFO] No sources found to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ git ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: D:\CI\git-plugin-master\target\surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running hudson.plugins.git.browser.BitbucketWebTest
Tests run: 6, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.059 sec
Running hudson.plugins.git.browser.BrowserChooserTest
Tests run: 5, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.311 sec
Running hudson.plugins.git.browser.GithubWebTest
Tests run: 6, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.002 sec
Running hudson.plugins.git.browser.GitoriousWebTest
Tests run: 6, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0 sec
Running hudson.plugins.git.browser.KilnGitTest
Tests run: 6, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0 sec
Running hudson.plugins.git.browser.RedmineWebTest
Tests run: 6, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0 sec
Running hudson.plugins.git.browser.RhodeCodeTest
Tests run: 6, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0 sec
Running hudson.plugins.git.browser.ViewGitWebTest
Tests run: 7, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0 sec
Running hudson.plugins.git.GitChangeLogParserTest
Exploding jenkins.war at C:\Users\msb4kor\.m2\repository\org\jenkins-ci\main\jenkins-war\1.480\jenkins-war-1.480-war-for-test.jar
Oct 22, 2013 9:15:53 PM org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog info
INFO: Logging to org.slf4j.impl.JDK14LoggerAdapter(org.mortbay.log) via org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog
Oct 22, 2013 9:15:53 PM org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog info
INFO: jetty-6.1.25
Oct 22, 2013 9:15:53 PM org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog info
INFO: NO JSP Support for , did not find org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet
Oct 22, 2013 9:15:53 PM org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog info
INFO: Copy D:\CI\git-plugin-master\target\jenkins-for-test to C:\Users\msb4kor\AppData\Local\Temp\Jetty_0_0_0_0_0_jenkins.for.test___.bj8wp3\webapp
Oct 22, 2013 9:15:59 PM org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog info
INFO: Started SocketConnector@0.0.0.0:55230
Oct 22, 2013 9:15:59 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Started initialization
Oct 22, 2013 9:16:15 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Listed all plugins
Oct 22, 2013 9:16:15 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Prepared all plugins
Oct 22, 2013 9:16:15 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Started all plugins
Oct 22, 2013 9:16:15 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Augmented all extensions
Oct 22, 2013 9:16:15 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Loaded all jobs
Oct 22, 2013 9:16:15 PM net.java.sezpoz.Index$LazyIndexIterator peek
WARNING: possible endless loop getting index for interface hudson.Extension from classLoader hudson.PluginManager$UberClassLoader
Oct 22, 2013 9:16:16 PM net.java.sezpoz.Index$LazyIndexIterator peek
WARNING: possible endless loop getting index for interface hudson.Extension from classLoader hudson.PluginManager$UberClassLoader
Oct 22, 2013 9:16:17 PM net.java.sezpoz.Index$LazyIndexIterator peek
WARNING: possible endless loop getting index for interface hudson.Extension from classLoader hudson.PluginManager$UberClassLoader
Oct 22, 2013 9:16:19 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Completed initialization
Oct 22, 2013 9:16:19 PM hudson.TcpSlaveAgentListener <init>
INFO: JNLP slave agent listener started on TCP port 55232
Oct 22, 2013 9:16:19 PM org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog info
INFO: jetty-6.1.25
Oct 22, 2013 9:16:19 PM org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog info
INFO: Started SocketConnector@0.0.0.0:55233
=== Starting GitChangeLogParserTest.testDuplicatesFiltered
Oct 22, 2013 9:16:19 PM org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog info
INFO: Stopped SocketConnector@0.0.0.0:55230
Oct 22, 2013 9:16:20 PM hudson.PluginWrapper stop
INFO: Stopping external-monitor-job
Oct 22, 2013 9:16:20 PM hudson.PluginWrapper stop
INFO: Stopping ldap
Oct 22, 2013 9:16:20 PM hudson.PluginWrapper stop
INFO: Stopping pam-auth
Oct 22, 2013 9:16:20 PM hudson.PluginWrapper stop
INFO: Stopping ant
Oct 22, 2013 9:16:20 PM hudson.PluginWrapper stop
INFO: Stopping javadoc
Oct 22, 2013 9:16:20 PM hudson.PluginWrapper stop
INFO: Stopping credentials
Oct 22, 2013 9:16:20 PM hudson.PluginWrapper stop
INFO: Stopping cvs
Oct 22, 2013 9:16:20 PM hudson.PluginWrapper stop
INFO: Stopping ssh-credentials
Oct 22, 2013 9:16:20 PM hudson.PluginWrapper stop
INFO: Stopping ssh-agent
Oct 22, 2013 9:16:20 PM hudson.PluginWrapper stop
INFO: Stopping git-client
Oct 22, 2013 9:16:20 PM hudson.PluginWrapper stop
INFO: Stopping token-macro
Oct 22, 2013 9:16:20 PM hudson.PluginWrapper stop
INFO: Stopping maven-plugin
Oct 22, 2013 9:16:20 PM hudson.PluginWrapper stop
INFO: Stopping multiple-scms
Oct 22, 2013 9:16:20 PM hudson.PluginWrapper stop
INFO: Stopping subversion
Oct 22, 2013 9:16:20 PM hudson.PluginWrapper stop
INFO: Stopping parameterized-trigger
Oct 22, 2013 9:16:20 PM hudson.PluginWrapper stop
INFO: Stopping promoted-builds
Oct 22, 2013 9:16:20 PM hudson.PluginWrapper stop
INFO: Stopping scm-api
Oct 22, 2013 9:16:20 PM hudson.PluginWrapper stop
INFO: Stopping ssh-slaves
Oct 22, 2013 9:16:20 PM hudson.PluginWrapper stop
INFO: Stopping translation
Oct 22, 2013 9:16:20 PM hudson.PluginWrapper stop
INFO: Stopping ui-samples-plugin
Oct 22, 2013 9:16:20 PM hudson.PluginWrapper stop
INFO: Stopping git
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 35.392 sec
Running hudson.plugins.git.GitChangeSetTest
```

And in a similar way, the test continues for hundreds of other classes. and finally ends with,

```
.
.
.
Oct 22, 2013 9:27:47 PM hudson.PluginWrapper stop
INFO: Stopping git
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 11.754 sec
Running InjectedTest
Oct 22, 2013 9:27:48 PM org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog info
INFO: jetty-6.1.25
Oct 22, 2013 9:27:48 PM org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog info
INFO: NO JSP Support for , did not find org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet
Oct 22, 2013 9:27:48 PM org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog info
INFO: Copy D:\CI\git-plugin-master\target\jenkins-for-test to C:\Users\msb4kor\AppData\Local\Temp\Jetty_0_0_0_0_0_jenkins.for.test___.bj8wp3\webapp
Oct 22, 2013 9:27:54 PM org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog info
INFO: Started SocketConnector@0.0.0.0:55681
Oct 22, 2013 9:27:54 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Started initialization
Oct 22, 2013 9:27:54 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Listed all plugins
Oct 22, 2013 9:27:54 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Prepared all plugins
Oct 22, 2013 9:27:54 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Started all plugins
Oct 22, 2013 9:27:54 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Augmented all extensions
Oct 22, 2013 9:27:54 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Loaded all jobs
Oct 22, 2013 9:27:54 PM net.java.sezpoz.Index$LazyIndexIterator peek
WARNING: possible endless loop getting index for interface hudson.Extension from classLoader hudson.PluginManager$UberClassLoader
Oct 22, 2013 9:27:55 PM net.java.sezpoz.Index$LazyIndexIterator peek
WARNING: possible endless loop getting index for interface hudson.Extension from classLoader hudson.PluginManager$UberClassLoader
Oct 22, 2013 9:27:55 PM net.java.sezpoz.Index$LazyIndexIterator peek
WARNING: possible endless loop getting index for interface hudson.Extension from classLoader hudson.PluginManager$UberClassLoader
Oct 22, 2013 9:27:57 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Completed initialization
Oct 22, 2013 9:27:57 PM hudson.TcpSlaveAgentListener <init>
INFO: JNLP slave agent listener started on TCP port 55682
Oct 22, 2013 9:27:58 PM org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog info
INFO: Stopped SocketConnector@0.0.0.0:55681
Oct 22, 2013 9:27:59 PM hudson.PluginWrapper stop
INFO: Stopping external-monitor-job
Oct 22, 2013 9:27:59 PM hudson.PluginWrapper stop
INFO: Stopping ldap
Oct 22, 2013 9:27:59 PM hudson.PluginWrapper stop
INFO: Stopping pam-auth
Oct 22, 2013 9:27:59 PM hudson.PluginWrapper stop
INFO: Stopping ant
Oct 22, 2013 9:27:59 PM hudson.PluginWrapper stop
INFO: Stopping javadoc
Oct 22, 2013 9:27:59 PM hudson.PluginWrapper stop
INFO: Stopping credentials
Oct 22, 2013 9:27:59 PM hudson.PluginWrapper stop
INFO: Stopping cvs
Oct 22, 2013 9:27:59 PM hudson.PluginWrapper stop
INFO: Stopping ssh-credentials
Oct 22, 2013 9:27:59 PM hudson.PluginWrapper stop
INFO: Stopping ssh-agent
Oct 22, 2013 9:27:59 PM hudson.PluginWrapper stop
INFO: Stopping git-client
Oct 22, 2013 9:27:59 PM hudson.PluginWrapper stop
INFO: Stopping token-macro
Oct 22, 2013 9:27:59 PM hudson.PluginWrapper stop
INFO: Stopping maven-plugin
Oct 22, 2013 9:27:59 PM hudson.PluginWrapper stop
INFO: Stopping multiple-scms
Oct 22, 2013 9:27:59 PM hudson.PluginWrapper stop
INFO: Stopping subversion
Oct 22, 2013 9:27:59 PM hudson.PluginWrapper stop
INFO: Stopping parameterized-trigger
Oct 22, 2013 9:27:59 PM hudson.PluginWrapper stop
INFO: Stopping promoted-builds
Oct 22, 2013 9:27:59 PM hudson.PluginWrapper stop
INFO: Stopping scm-api
Oct 22, 2013 9:27:59 PM hudson.PluginWrapper stop
INFO: Stopping ssh-slaves
Oct 22, 2013 9:27:59 PM hudson.PluginWrapper stop
INFO: Stopping translation
Oct 22, 2013 9:27:59 PM hudson.PluginWrapper stop
INFO: Stopping ui-samples-plugin
Oct 22, 2013 9:27:59 PM hudson.PluginWrapper stop
INFO: Stopping git
Oct 22, 2013 9:27:59 PM org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog info
INFO: jetty-6.1.25
Oct 22, 2013 9:27:59 PM org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog info
INFO: NO JSP Support for , did not find org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet
Oct 22, 2013 9:27:59 PM org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog info
INFO: Copy D:\CI\git-plugin-master\target\jenkins-for-test to C:\Users\msb4kor\AppData\Local\Temp\Jetty_0_0_0_0_0_jenkins.for.test___.bj8wp3\webapp
Oct 22, 2013 9:28:05 PM org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog info
INFO: Started SocketConnector@0.0.0.0:55684
Oct 22, 2013 9:28:05 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Started initialization
Oct 22, 2013 9:28:05 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Listed all plugins
Oct 22, 2013 9:28:05 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Prepared all plugins
Oct 22, 2013 9:28:05 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Started all plugins
Oct 22, 2013 9:28:05 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Augmented all extensions
Oct 22, 2013 9:28:05 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Loaded all jobs
Oct 22, 2013 9:28:05 PM net.java.sezpoz.Index$LazyIndexIterator peek
WARNING: possible endless loop getting index for interface hudson.Extension from classLoader hudson.PluginManager$UberClassLoader
Oct 22, 2013 9:28:06 PM net.java.sezpoz.Index$LazyIndexIterator peek
WARNING: possible endless loop getting index for interface hudson.Extension from classLoader hudson.PluginManager$UberClassLoader
Oct 22, 2013 9:28:06 PM net.java.sezpoz.Index$LazyIndexIterator peek
WARNING: possible endless loop getting index for interface hudson.Extension from classLoader hudson.PluginManager$UberClassLoader
Oct 22, 2013 9:28:07 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Completed initialization
Oct 22, 2013 9:28:07 PM hudson.TcpSlaveAgentListener <init>
INFO: JNLP slave agent listener started on TCP port 55685
=== Starting CliSanityTest.testCliSanity
Oct 22, 2013 9:28:07 PM org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog info
INFO: Stopped SocketConnector@0.0.0.0:55684
Oct 22, 2013 9:28:07 PM hudson.PluginWrapper stop
INFO: Stopping external-monitor-job
Oct 22, 2013 9:28:07 PM hudson.PluginWrapper stop
INFO: Stopping ldap
Oct 22, 2013 9:28:07 PM hudson.PluginWrapper stop
INFO: Stopping pam-auth
Oct 22, 2013 9:28:07 PM hudson.PluginWrapper stop
INFO: Stopping ant
Oct 22, 2013 9:28:07 PM hudson.PluginWrapper stop
INFO: Stopping javadoc
Oct 22, 2013 9:28:07 PM hudson.PluginWrapper stop
INFO: Stopping credentials
Oct 22, 2013 9:28:07 PM hudson.PluginWrapper stop
INFO: Stopping cvs
Oct 22, 2013 9:28:07 PM hudson.PluginWrapper stop
INFO: Stopping ssh-credentials
Oct 22, 2013 9:28:07 PM hudson.PluginWrapper stop
INFO: Stopping ssh-agent
Oct 22, 2013 9:28:07 PM hudson.PluginWrapper stop
INFO: Stopping git-client
Oct 22, 2013 9:28:07 PM hudson.PluginWrapper stop
INFO: Stopping token-macro
Oct 22, 2013 9:28:07 PM hudson.PluginWrapper stop
INFO: Stopping maven-plugin
Oct 22, 2013 9:28:07 PM hudson.PluginWrapper stop
INFO: Stopping multiple-scms
Oct 22, 2013 9:28:07 PM hudson.PluginWrapper stop
INFO: Stopping subversion
Oct 22, 2013 9:28:07 PM hudson.PluginWrapper stop
INFO: Stopping parameterized-trigger
Oct 22, 2013 9:28:07 PM hudson.PluginWrapper stop
INFO: Stopping promoted-builds
Oct 22, 2013 9:28:07 PM hudson.PluginWrapper stop
INFO: Stopping scm-api
Oct 22, 2013 9:28:07 PM hudson.PluginWrapper stop
INFO: Stopping ssh-slaves
Oct 22, 2013 9:28:07 PM hudson.PluginWrapper stop
INFO: Stopping translation
Oct 22, 2013 9:28:07 PM hudson.PluginWrapper stop
INFO: Stopping ui-samples-plugin
Oct 22, 2013 9:28:07 PM hudson.PluginWrapper stop
INFO: Stopping git
Tests run: 31, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 19.977 sec

Results :

Failed tests:   testMergeAndPushWithSkipTagEnabled(hudson.plugins.git.GitPublisherTest): commitFileBase file not found in workspace
  testMatrixBuild(hudson.plugins.git.GitPublisherTest): unexpected build status; build log was:(..)
  testMergeAndPush(hudson.plugins.git.GitPublisherTest): commitFileBase file not found in workspace
  testBasicRemotePoll(hudson.plugins.git.GitSCMTest): commitFile1 file not found in workspace
  testEmailCommitter(hudson.plugins.git.GitSCMTest): class hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM is missing its descriptor
  testBasicExcludedRegion(hudson.plugins.git.GitSCMTest): commitFile1 file not found in workspace
  testIncludedRegionWithDeeperCommits(hudson.plugins.git.GitSCMTest): commitFile1 file not found in workspace
  testFetchFromMultipleRepositories(hudson.plugins.git.GitSCMTest): commitFile1 file not found in workspace
  testBasic(hudson.plugins.git.GitSCMTest): commitFile1 file not found in workspace
  testMerge(hudson.plugins.git.GitSCMTest): commitFileBase file not found in workspace
  testMultipleBranchBuild(hudson.plugins.git.GitSCMTest): commitFile1 file not found in workspace
  testBasicIncludedRegion(hudson.plugins.git.GitSCMTest): commitFile1 file not found in workspace
  testBasicExcludedUser(hudson.plugins.git.GitSCMTest): commitFile1 file not found in workspace
  testMergeFailed(hudson.plugins.git.GitSCMTest): commitFileBase file not found in workspace
  testSubmoduleFixup(hudson.plugins.git.GitSCMTest): unexpected build status; build log was:(..)
  testCheckoutToSpecificBranch(hudson.plugins.git.GitSCMTest): unexpected build status; build log was:(..)
  testNodeEnvVarsAvailable(hudson.plugins.git.GitSCMTest): commitFile1 file not found in workspace
  testBasicInSubdir(hudson.plugins.git.GitSCMTest)
  testBranchIsAvailableInEvironment(hudson.plugins.git.GitSCMTest): commitFile1 file not found in workspace
  testAuthorOrCommitterTrue(hudson.plugins.git.GitSCMTest): commitFile1 file not found in workspace
  testEnvironmentVariableExpansion(hudson.plugins.git.GitSCMTest): a.txt file not found in workspace
  testBasicWithSlave(hudson.plugins.git.GitSCMTest): commitFile1 file not found in workspace
  testExcludedRegionMultiCommit(hudson.plugins.git.GitSCMTest): initialFile file not found in workspace
  testAuthorOrCommitterFalse(hudson.plugins.git.GitSCMTest): commitFile1 file not found in workspace
  testBasicWithSlaveNoExecutorsOnMaster(hudson.plugins.git.GitSCMTest): commitFile1 file not found in workspace
  testMergeWithSlave(hudson.plugins.git.GitSCMTest): commitFileBase file not found in workspace
  testPleaseDontContinueAnyway(hudson.plugins.git.GitSCMTest): unexpected build status; build log was:(..)
  testGitSCMCanBuildAgainstTags(hudson.plugins.git.GitSCMTest): class hudson.plugins.git.util.DefaultBuildChooser is missing its descriptor
  testNewCommitToUntrackedBranchDoesNotTriggerBuild(hudson.plugins.git.GitSCMTest): commitFile1 file not found in workspace
  testMergeFailedWithSlave(hudson.plugins.git.GitSCMTest): commitFileBase file not found in workspace
  testDoNotifyCommitWithOneBranch(hudson.plugins.git.GitStatusTest): (..)
  testDoNotifyCommitWithTwoBranches(hudson.plugins.git.GitStatusTest): (..)
  testDoNotifyCommitWithNoBranches(hudson.plugins.git.GitStatusTest): (..)
  testBasic(hudson.plugins.git.MultipleSCMTest): unexpected build status; build log was:(..)

Tests run: 146, Failures: 34, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 12:44.965s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Oct 22 21:28:08 IST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 32M/322M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) on project git: There are test failures.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please refer to D:\CI\git-plugin-master\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Comment: Can you delete surefirebooter9216743649885094480.jar manually?

Comment: @vikingsteve sorry, but i don`t have surefirebooter9216743649885094480.jar in the repository.

Comment: Well it exists (or existed) on your file system, thus causing maven clean to fail. If you can delete the whole `target` folder, try to rebuild...

Comment: @RomanVottner but that question also doesn`t have a solution.

Comment: thanks @vikingsteve. I deleted the target folder and it worked for me.
But now when i start a maven install, i am getting lot of errors which i have uploaded above.

Comment: thanks @RomanVottner. please help me with maven install error also.

Comment: Thanks again @RomanVottner. but after trying/googling so much i feel the problem is coming because i downloaded the plugin from github into my pc and imported into eclipse using maven. Since there is an option in eclipse as to add the archetypes in file->import->other->maven Project->next->addarchetype and v need to give the groupid, artifact Id, version and url. If v have any idea of these parameters, could u pls post the working combination of these fields??

Comment: @RomanVottner how can i import the git plugin using "addarchetype"?
I feel what and all errors i`m geeting in the project won`t be there if we import it through this "addarchetype".. So, i want the working combination of the  groupid, artifact Id, version and url.. i`ve tried different other combinations looking at opm.xml. Could you guys suggest any?

Comment: @RomanVottner the "git clone https://github.com/jenkinsci/git-plugin.git" throws this error 
"Cloning into 'git-plugin'...
error: Couldn't resolve host 'github.com' while accessing https://github.com/jem
kins/git-plugin.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack
fatal: HTTP request failed"

Comment: @RomanVottner even git clone git@github.com:jenkinsci/git-plugin.git also throws the same error as before. I tried importing the project as given in the below link.
https://github.com/OneBusAway/onebusaway/wiki/Importing-source-code-into-Eclipse 
but that didn`t even solved my purpose. When i give run as-> maven build, i am getting the error i faced in the second part of the error message i posted above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"configRoundtrip(FreeStyleProject) is ambiguous for the type GitSCMTest" is certainly a problem and has been around for a couple of years. The class hierarchy of GitSCMTest is full of multilevel generics, which IMHO is the source of the problem.
Anyway, if you change the offending lines in GitSCMTest.java to this:

```
configRoundtrip((Item)p);
```

then the error should go away.